# BigIP - Tomcat 8 connection refused on upgrade from tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, f5, big-ip

Tomcat starts listening on the port and the application also gets deployed but when I access the URL I get connection refused error.
Is there any issue with BigIP not able to recognize the port opened by tomcat 8 on the server?

Although when I revert back to tomcat 6(start and stop it) and then again try with tomcat 8 it sometimes starts receiving connections which is weird and I am not able to find the reason.
What could be the issue?

```
Jun 13, 2017 5:56:32 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Valve} Setting property 'resolveHosts' to 'false' did not find a matching property.

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: :/myPath/lib

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9030"]

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 854 ms

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:32 AM org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase open
SEVERE: The specified user database [conf/tomcat-users.xml] could not be found

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:33 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippin
g unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /mypath/MyWar.war

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:43 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippin
g unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Jun 13, 2017 5:56:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

Jun 13, 2017 5:57:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'myServlet'

Jun 13, 2017 5:57:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /mypath/MyWar.war has finished in 33,424 ms

Jun 13, 2017 5:57:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9030"]'

Jun 13, 2017 5:57:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 33845 ms
```

Comment: Add the relevant part of the console / log file output.  What do you mean the "restful endpoints become unreachable"? May it be that your WebApplication will not start up? Without log files / console output it's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for the response andih. Please ignore restful endpoint. I have edited the question. Kindly let me know your views

Comment: And in this case you could access the application using port 9030? How does a log file / console output look like when you can't?

Comment: Nothing gets printed in log file(catalina,access logs etc) or console. telnet works.

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing gets printed"?  You said you (re)start you tomcat and it starts listening but nothing gets printed?  And what do you mean with telnet work? What's the output of telnet when you get connection refused and which tool get's the connection refused?

Comment: When I access from browser I get connection refused.   When I revert tomcat to version 6 with which there are no issues(start and stop it) and then again go back to tomcat 8 it starts receiving connections. Telnet is just to check whether port is open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146543/discussion-between-andih-and-akhilesh-n).

Answer (score 1):

> Each incoming request requires a thread for the duration of that request. If more simultaneous requests are received than can be handled by the currently available request processing threads, additional threads will be created up to the configured maximum (the value of the maxThreads attribute). If still more simultaneous requests are received, they are stacked up inside the server socket created by the Connector, up to the configured maximum (the value of the acceptCount attribute). Any further simultaneous requests will receive "connection refused" errors, until resources are available to process them.

Refer more at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Thanks for the response Omkar but in my app MaxThreads are set to http.port.maxThreads=100 and I am not able to even accesss application. Hence not even one thread is created